# Implementing in-memory instances of an object in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there anyway to implement in-memory or fixed/hardcoded object instances in NHibernate that appear to all intents and purposes to be real instances of the object read from the database?

I have a historical database that has a number of missing foreign key values against a number of different tables as they are fixed/hard coded in the old DAL.

This is causing me problems in my NHibernate mapping.

An example of this would be a fixed immutable user, say 'ADMIN' that exists in code but not in the database. This 'ADMIN' user is still used in various foreign keys so needs to exist in NHibernate so that it can manage the FK mapping.

I've managed cheat loading by using a sql view which has the hard coded rows explicitly added, but of course I can't write to a view like that so need an alternative solution.

I did find a reference to the uNhAddIns WellKnowInstanceType that seems to do something similar, but I couldn't get to to work.

Anyone have any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

one trick i can think of is attaching the imaginary User instance to the session befor querying using `sess.Lock(admin, LockMode.None);` that should take care of the reference. But I#m not sure what happens when eager loading the reference.